# Не могу понять почему выражение "always true"

Tags: java

Дан метод

```
static char sign() {
    System.out.println("Введите знак");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char sign = scanner.next().charAt(0);

    if(sign != '-' || sign != '+' || sign != '*' || sign != '%'){
        System.out.println("Неверный знак, введите снова");
        sign();
    }
    System.out.println(sign);
    return sign;
}
```

Почему сравнение

```
if(sign != '-' || sign != '+' || sign != '*' || sign != '%') *always true*
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

потому что `sign` **всегда** не равен **как минимум трем** символам из этих четырех. Вместо `||` нужно использовать `&&`.

Comment: `sign` действительно всегда будет не равен одному из перечисленных символов. Но значит ли это, что нужно использовать `&&` вместо `||`? Сдаётся мне, что не обязательно. Это зависит от условий, которые автор вопроса не сообщил. Может быть нужно использовать `==` вместо `!=`, например

Comment: @Sergey В этом случае это очень маловероятно.